# "If" "else" statement with syntax error

Tags: javascript, if-statement, syntax

having problems with the following code syntax error at line 11, 12, 13.

```
// Get the field values
var DP = +getField("DESIGN_Projection").value;
var TC = +getField("ASBUILT_Top_of_Concrete").value;
var GE = +getField("ASBUILT_Ground_Elevation").value;



// If DP is N/A, set this field to display N/A
If (DP === N/A); {
    event.value = "NA";  // display N/A in this field
} else 
{
    //...otherwise, set this field value to the result of the following calculation
    event.value = ((TC - GE) * 1000);    
}
```

Comment: This isn't java is it? It looks like javascript to me.

Answer (score 2):

You have several issues with this line:

```
If (DP === N/A); {
```

First, note that `If` should be in lower-case (`if`).  Second, note that you have a semicolon after the `if` statement.  This makes the language think that your code should be interpreted as

```
If (DP === N/A)
   ;  // Do nothing

{
    event.value = "NA";  // display N/A in this field
} else 
{
    //...otherwise, set this field value to the result of the following calculation
    event.value = ((TC - GE) * 1000);    
}
```

From this, it should be clearer what the error is - there's a mysterious `else` floating around!

If you remove the semicolon and change `If` to `if`, the error should go away.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Basic setup of an if statement is simply "if (<condition>) { something; }

Answer (score 0):

`If` should be `if` (Lower case i)

Also remove the `;` from the if.

```
if (DP === N/A) {
    event.value = "NA";  // display N/A in this field
} else
```

Answer (score 0):

there's a semicolon at the end of your if statement.

`if` should also be lowercase